# Time and space complexities of D* and D* Lite

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, path-finding, incremental-search, d-star

What are the time and space complexities of D* and D* Lite? How to derive those?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900718/where-can-i-find-information-on-the-d-or-d-lite-pathfinding-algorithm

Comment: I am asking about the complexity and not the reference material

Comment: D* Lite runs like an A-star so for the first iteration it is O(n) in Time (where n is the total number of nodes in grid) in the worst case. For the path updates, it depends on the number of obstacles that have been updated and in the worst case can be much worse than A-star. Time Complexity doesn't make a lot of sense for these kind of heuristic search algorithms as in worst case a lot of them run to O(n). Eg. BFS, Dijkstra's, A-star even though A-star runs much faster than BFS.

Comment: For the space complexity, in the naive implementation all the nodes that have been searched need to be stored so again it is O(n) in worst case